# Как вызвать action в extraReducers, объявленный в reducers в том же createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux

я пишу функционал удаления пользователя. Я бы хотел чтобы со стороны клиента удаление происходило только после положительного результата с сервера.

Каким образом я могу это сделать со следующим кодом?

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import useHttp from '../../../hooks/http.hook';


const initialState = {
    usersList: [],
    usersToDelete: [],
    usersLoadingStatus: 'idle',
    userDeletingStatus: 'idle',
}




export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk(
    'users/fetchUsers',
    (pageNum) => {
        const request = useHttp();
        return request(`/admin/users/?page=${pageNum}`);
    }
);

export const deleteUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'users/deleteUser',
    (id) => {
        const request = useHttp('DELETE');
        return request(`/admin/users/${298}`);
    }
)




const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        deleteUserOnClient: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action);
            console.log(`action in basic reducer`)
            state.usersList = state.usersList.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.data.id);
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchUsers.pending, state => {state.usersLoadingStatus = 'fetching'})
            .addCase(fetchUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.usersLoadingStatus = 'idle';  
                state.usersList = state.usersList.concat(action.payload.data);
            })
            .addCase(fetchUsers.rejected, state => {state.usersLoadingStatus = 'error'});
        builder
            .addCase(deleteUser.pending, state => {state.userDeletingStatus = 'deleting'})
            .addCase(deleteUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log(`action id in fulfilled promise ${action.payload.data.id}`)
                (deleteUserOnClient(action.payload.data.id));
                
                state.userDeletingStatus = 'idle';
            })
            .addCase(deleteUser.rejected, state => {state.userDeletingStatus = 'error'})
    }
});


const {actions, reducer } = usersSlice;
const {
    deleteUserOnClient
} = actions;


export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение своей проблемы.

Достаточно было создать нужный action в `reducers`, а затем обратиться к `sliceName.caseReducers.actionName` и все заработало.

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        deleteUserOnClient: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action);
            console.log(`action in basic reducer`)
            state.usersList = state.usersList.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.data.id);
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchUsers.pending, state => {state.usersLoadingStatus = 'fetching'})
            .addCase(fetchUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.usersLoadingStatus = 'idle';  
                state.usersList = state.usersList.concat(action.payload.data);
            })
            .addCase(fetchUsers.rejected, state => {state.usersLoadingStatus = 'error'});
        builder
            .addCase(deleteUser.pending, state => {state.userDeletingStatus = 'deleting'})
            .addCase(deleteUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log(`action id in fulfilled promise ${action.payload.data.id}`)
                usersSlice.caseReducers.deleteUserOnClient()    // THIS LINE
                
                state.userDeletingStatus = 'idle';
            })
            .addCase(deleteUser.rejected, state => {state.userDeletingStatus = 'error'})
    }
});

const { reducer } = usersSlice;

export default reducer;
```